# Named route helper in javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I'm doing some ajax stuff, I can get where a form 'normally' goes by grabbing its 'action' attribute:

```
'Sign Up': ->
     post_url = $('#form').attr 'action' #=> users/sign_up (for example)
```

However, if I have this in my routes file:

```
post 'users/sign_up', to: 'users#create', as: :user_create
```

I'm wondering why I can't just do this:

```
'Sign Up': ->
     post_url = <%= user_create_path %>
```

While erb tags are supported, I get this error when using a named route:

```
undefined local variable or method 'user_create_path'
```

**Just wondering why this is happening...** I mean using the named route helpers could be excellent. Although it may be less confusing to grab it from the form. Still think rails / coffeescript gem should implement this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The named routes helpers are probably not being included outside a controller/view.
You can access them in `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_create_path`.

You could also use a gem like [js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes) to do the job for you.